# Evaluating a numerical integration with infinity as limit

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to evaluate a numerical integration (to get an expression of the constant `Ω`)

Suppose that

```
h[x_] := 1/(1 + a x^2)
```

and

```
P=Integrate[x/(h[x] Exp[x/(h[x]) Ω] - 1), {x, 0, ∞}]
```

where `a` and `Ω` are constants. My aim is to get an expression for `Ω` in terms of `a` and `P` after evaluating the integral, but the Mathematica is getting stuck.

Any suggestion to do the above or simplify the problem will be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are trying to solve `Ω` in terms of `a` and the result of the integral `P`.

I'd do something like this.

```
f[a_?NumericQ, P_?NumericQ] := Module[{},
  h[x_]:= 1/(1 + a x^2);
  FindRoot[
    NIntegrate[x/(h[x] Exp[x/(h[x]) Ω] - 1),{x, 0, Infinity}] == P, 
  {Ω, 2}]] // Quiet   (*Maybe you would like to change the initial guess*)

f[3,0.6]
(*{Ω -> 1.2752}*)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan for your suggestion. Yes, I want to get Ω in terms of a and P. So, if I want to get such an expression of Ω (not a value evaluated at specific a and P), I am a bit confused if  I can still use NIntegrate.

Comment: @reach2brb You're welcome! I'm not sure if that integral has a closed form. If it doesn't, you can't have an expression and your only hope is to find the values numerically, like I did.